# Ajax on the Administration Side of plugin - wp_localize_script - how to pass value from JQuery to PHP function in class?

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I have built a plugin and  I need to use ajax in the admin and have followed the documentation here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

However, this is out of date and I cannot find any good examples to get it working.

I use a class for the plugin and have the jquery in a seperate file.  So apparently I need to use the **wp_localize_script** to pass the variables.  This is where I am struggling to understand how to pass the variable from the selectObject.value in the JQuery to the PHP function.

Can anyone assist?

**myplugin-admin.js**

```
function getFeatureIDs(selectObject){
    var value = selectObject.value;  
    console.log(value);  //I want to pass this value but it doesnt work
    console.log(ajax_object.we_value); 

    var data = {
        'action': 'get_etim',
        'whatever': ajax_object.we_value   
    };
   
    
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);

    });

}
```

**class-myplugin-admin.php**

```
class myplugin_Admin {
    private $myplugin;
    private $version;

    public function __construct($myplugin,$version ) {
        
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_etim', array( $this, 'get_etim' ) );

    }

    public function enqueue_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_script( $this->myplugin, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/myplugin-admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );

        wp_localize_script( $this->myplugin, 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
    }

    public function get_etim() {

        echo $_POST['whatever'];

        wp_die();
    }
}
```

**Results in console:**

```
EC003025
1234
https://mytestsite.plesk.page/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Alert is,

> "Got this from the server: 1234"

This needs to be the select variable.

Comment: try passing the value you wanted aka `value`, rather than `ajax_object.we_value`. Keep in mind that this is leaving WordPress and going into generic javascript, nothing in this question requires WordPress knowledge, and any javascript developer can help.

Comment: Ah seems obvious now, I was fixtated on the ajax_object as shown in the example in the documentation.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your `value` JS variable that you created in the data that gets sent to your php function via ajax like:

```
var data = {
    'action': 'get_etim',
    'whatever': ajax_object.we_value,
    'select_value': value   
};
```

Then in the php function that Ajax sends to  you can use `select_value` the same way you used `whatever` in your code like:

```
echo “Whatever is: “ . $_POST[‘whatever’] . “, and Select value is: “ . $_POST[‘select_value’];
```

Don’t forget to use a nonce, sanitize input data, and escape output.